# Get MS Exchange mail for all group members

Tags: node.js, azure, outlook, exchange-server, office365

Is it possible to get all email from all mailboxes in MS Exchange?
I have full rights in Azure console for Office365 exchange online.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DF5n5.png

But when I'm trying make an request to

```
https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/Users('user@company.onmicrosoft.com')/Inbox/Messages
```

getting an error "The specified object was not found in the store."

But for logged in admin

```
https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/Me/Inbox/Messages

https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/Users('admin@company.onmicrosoft.com')/Inbox/Messages
```

works well.

What should I do, to get access for read mail for all my users in office 365?

Comment: Are you trying to use EWS and impersonation?

Comment: I want do this through rest api. I tried this https://support.software.dell.com/kb/SOL81894 but no result.

Answer (score 0):

The current authorization model for Office 365 Mail, Calendar and Contacts services does not currently expose a permission that would allow your app to query other users' mailboxes.

Answer (score 0):

The REST API consent flow allows you to register a web app that requires Admin consent. Once your web app has been given the global admin consent, it should be able to access information for all users under that tenant.

See the following post for more information:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn605895(v=office.15).aspx#ConNavExample_config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn605895%28v=office.15%29.aspx#ConNavExample_config)