# Accessing office 365 data using service account

Tags: ms-office, exchangewebservices

Similar to the question here [Accessing Office 365 user mail data with admin authorisation only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24241161/accessing-office-365-user-mail-data-with-admin-authorisation-only)

Currently i am implementing an application that will access a set of mailboxes on Office365 using a service account.

There is an MSDN blog post announcing oauth support for Office 365 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2014/03/25/using-oauth2-to-access-calendar-contact-and-mail-api-in-exchange-online-in-office-365.aspx

Can our app use the technique in that link and get authorization from the administrator for the set of mailboxes using the service account for this "group" of mailboxes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using OAuth with the new REST APIs, an administrator can consent on behalf of their entire Office 365 organization. They cannot consent only on behalf of a subset of users.